# syslogd not ouputting year information

Tags: linux, syslog, busybox, busybox-init

I updated busybox to 1.35.0 and had the same settings as earlier but for some reasons the syslogd is not outputting year in the timestamp information. Prior to this I was using busybox 1.19.3 and it was working fine. I tried to find that if any information related to year got changed but not succesful with that.

Can you help in getting the 'year' information as well in the time stamp.Thanks!

```
Apr 10 07:59:51 mytestapp: Mytestapp started
Apr 10 07:59:51 mytestapp: Mytestapp log1
```

Older logs:

```
Apr 08 11:54:52 2023 mytestapp: Mytestapp started
Apr 08 11:54:52 2023 mytestapp: Mytestapp log1
```

PS: I cannot use rsylog/syslog-ng.